# Question about the threading module and Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading

I'd like to ask a question regarding the threading module in the context of my Raspberry Pi project.

Does spawning new threads in the script actually use a different hardware thread?

And if so, is there a limit of threads I can make in the said script? (considering there's a limited amount of physical threads/cores onboard)

Comment: AFAIK, there's no such thing as a *"hardware thread"*. Threading is a software concept. As for your second question, you can start as many threads as you want and that will help if they are I/O bound, but if they are CPU-bound, there is little point starting more than 4 as RasPi has 4 cores. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a couple of modules written up, one of which parses inputs based on currently connected pins, and another that executes functions based on the arrangement of pins held in a specific formation for a period of time. The thing is that the parser requires a specific sleep time (which currently also slows down the execution of the command module).
I was planning on using multiple threads for a while to fix this problem and here we are with some leftover questions I still had.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, when a so-called, "hyper-threaded," CPU core has enough registers to hold N complete execution contexts (where N usually equals 2), it's common for people to say that the core supports N _Hardware Threads_.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thank you for taking the time to explain that - I hadn't come across that usage. I don't think it applies here though, because you can still run more threads than you have execution contexts if you want to, and also the ARM CPU on the RasPi doesn't do HyperThreading - it is just 4 physical CPU cores.

Comment: You should be fine using threads if it's to allow one thread to sleep because that will release the GIL allowing the other to make progress. You will only have problems if your "calculation/processing" task runs flat out, full speed and hogs the CPU... in which case you can normally pretty simply switch to multi-processing unless you need to frequently move vast quantities of data between different processes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Agreed. so-called "hardware threads" are not threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read mora on [this article, no.](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Parallelising-Python-with-Threading-and-Multiprocessing/)

Unfortunately the internals of the main Python interpreter, CPython, negate the possibility of true multi-threading due to a process known as the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL).

Comment: Looks like the multiprocessing library is something closer to what I'm searching for. Thanks.